# Deploy same code to two apps with different Procfile in Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm triggering Heroku deployment from Bitbucket Pipeline using this shell script: 
https://bitbucket.org/spittet/heroku-deploy/src/master/heroku-deploy.sh

This works fine but now I'd like for this to deploy to two Heroku apps with the same code, just different Procfiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official way, but there is a build pack that supports multiple Procfiles:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi-procfile

For each app set the PROCFILE variable

```
heroku config:set PROCFILE=relative/path/to/Procfile -a <app>
```

And then add the buildpack

```
heroku buildpacks:add -a <app> https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi-procfile
```

Comment: nice one, I'll check that out